# How to pattern match an abstract data type when the data constructor isn't in scope?

Tags: haskell, parsec

I'm writing a parser library using Parsec combinators, and I want to unit test some of my parsers. So I have a simple parser:

```hs
dash :: GenParser Char st Char
dash = char '-'
```

I'd like to write some tests for it. The positive test is pretty easy:

```hs
spec :: Spec
spec = do
  describe "dash" $ do
    it "parses a dash" $
      parse dash "N/A" "-" `shouldBe` (Right '-')
```

I'd like to write a negative test as well. When the parser doesn't match, it returns `Left` of a `ParseError`. I'd like to write a test that validates the exact message that the `ParseError` contains. So what I'd really like to do is something like

```hs
spec :: Spec
spec = do
  describe "dash" $ do
    it "doesn't parse an underscore" $
      parse dash "N/A" "_" `shouldSatisfy` (hasErrorMessage "not a dash")

hasErrorMessage (Left (ParseError _ msgs)) expected = msg == expected
hasErrorMessage _ expected = False
```

But I'm having trouble writing this sort of code, since the `ParseError` data constructor isn't exported from `Text.Parsec.Error`.

Is there any way to use pattern matching on types where no data constructor for the type is in scope?

I know I could write `hasErrorMessage` something like

```
hasErrorMessage :: String -> (Either ParseError a) -> Bool
hasErrorMessage expected (Left pe) = elem expected $ fmap messageString (errorMessages pe)
```

but I'd like to understand this nuance, too.

Comment: You cannot. That's the point of not exporting them.

Comment: Thanks. Can you elaborate on what the perceived advantage is to not permitting it? Is it just plain old implementation hiding?

Comment: Yes implementation hiding would be the most obvious reason for not exporting the constructors.

Answer (score 3):

Although the data constructor isn't exported, functions to access its parameters are. You can use these in combination with [view patterns](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/8.6.5/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#extension-ViewPatterns) to sort of get what you want. In your case, the pattern `(errorMessages -> msgs)` can stand in almost perfectly for `(ParseError _ msgs)`, with two caveats:

1. You need `{-# LANGUAGE ViewPatterns #-}` to use this feature.
2. `errorMessages` sorts the messages, which a pattern match on the data constructor wouldn't do.

You can even use this technique with [pattern synonyms](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/8.6.5/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#pattern-synonyms) to make a fake data constructor, so you can use the exact same syntax you would otherwise:

```
{-# LANGUAGE PatternSynonyms, ViewPatterns #-}
pattern ParseError pos msgs <- ((,) <$> errorPos <*> errorMessages -> (pos, msgs)) where
        ParseError pos msgs = foldr addErrorMessage (newErrorUnknown pos) msgs
```